# Angular route not entering the resolve function

Tags: angularjs, q, ngroute, route-provider

I'm adding route authentication to my angular app.

For some reason when I try to navigate to the `logentries` view, I cannot get the code in the `resolve` function to execute.

I've added a breakpoint using **Chrome developer tools**, but it doesn't get hit.

The view does get loaded, however.

I thought the resolve would get hit before the controller is instantiated and the view rendered.

Why isn't it?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .config(appConfig)
        .run(routeAuthentication);

    routeAuthentication.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location'];

    function routeAuthentication($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
            if (rejection === 'Not Authenticated') {
                console.log('Not Authenticated for Route');
                $location.path('/');
            }
        });
    }

    appConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function appConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/logentries", {
            templateUrl: "app/views/logEntries.html",
            controller: "logEntries",
            resolve: function ($q, $location) {
                // Code not entering here as far as I can tell.
                var deferred = $q.defer(); 
                deferred.resolve();
                if (true) { // TODO - use authenticationServce
                    $location.path('/login');
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        })
        // other routes
    };
})();
```

Comment: `resolve` should be a property, not a function

Comment: I got the resolve function from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788586/angularjs-handle-routing-before-they-load