# 'invocables' must be an object

Tags: angularjs

I have a state as following :

```
.state('core.recover', {
   url: '/recover',
   controller: 'RecoverPasswordCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/recoverAccount/recover-password.html'
})
```

I want when I enter to this state to check something before loading the template, in this case I want to call an api that checks for something if the promise is successful it will continue and display the template, otherwise it will redirect the user to another state.

I tried to do this on the top of the controller but I always see the template for a moment then it redirects me, so I tried to use resolve as in this post :

[AngularJS | handle routing before they load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788586/angularjs-handle-routing-before-they-load)

As following :

```
.state('core.recover', {
        url: '/recover',
        controller: 'RecoverPasswordCtrl',
        resolve: function(recoverAccountService, $location, $state, $q) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve();
          recoverAccountService.get({email:$location.search().email, verificationKey:$location.search().verificationKey})
            .$promise.then(function (result) {}).catch(function (err) {
            $state.go("candidature.pre");
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/recoverAccount/recover-password.html'
      })
```

but it didn't work and I'm getting this error in the browser's console :

```
Error: 'invocables' must be an object
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the correct syntax, `uiRouter` is expecting as entry for `resolve` an object, which keys it will try to evaluate.

Lets abbreviate your resolving function as `aimadResolver`, such that

```
var aimadResolver = function(recoverAccountService, $location, $state, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    recoverAccountService.get({ email: $location.search().email, verificationKey: $location.search().verificationKey })
        .$promise.then(function(result) {}).catch(function(err) {
            $state.go("candidature.pre");
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Of course, this is not mandatory, but I'm doing it for the sake of readability. Then, your state definition should be as follows:

```
state('core.recover', {
    url: '/recover',
    controller: 'RecoverPasswordCtrl',
    resolve: {'yourResolverName': aimaidResolver}
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/recoverAccount/recover-password.html'
})
```

Don't forget to inject `yourResolverName` in `RecoverPasswordCtrl`, or else your controller will be instantiated without waiting anyway. Source: [look for the resolve examples](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

**On the side**
I'd like to point out that your use of deferred objects doesn't make sense. You're immediately resolving your deferred object on the second line within your function, which means that `recoverAccountservice.get()` could still be pending while `RecoverPasswordCtrl` is already being instantiated. Assuming that `recoverAccountservice.get()` returns a promise (and if it doesn't, you should change it such that it does), you can more efficiently write:

```
var aimadResolver = function(recoverAccountService, $location, $state, $q) {
    return recoverAccountService.get({... })
        .then(function(result) {
            // do nothing? Apparently you only want to $state.go on a rejection of the promise
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            $state.go("candidature.pre");
            return $q.when()
        })
}
```

More on the use of `$q.when()` versus `deferred` can be found [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/).